# Checking compatibility of two python functions (or methods)

Tags: python, reflection

Is there a possibility to check if two python functions are interchangeable? For instance, if I have

```
def foo(a, b):
    pass
def bar(x, y):
    pass
def baz(x,y,z):
    pass
```

I would like a function `is_compatible(a,b)` that returns True when passed foo and bar, but False when passed bar and baz, so I can check if they're interchangeable before actually calling either of them.

Comment: What does "compatible" mean?  Where does `def quux(*args)` fit?

Comment: @S.Lott I would view compatibility as a commutative non-transitive weak operation and consider that `def foo(*args)` and `def bar(a, b)` are compatible and vice versa, and `def baz(a=7, /, **kwargs) and `def bar(a, b)` are compatible and vice versa, but `def foo(*args)` and `def baz(a=7, /, **kwargs)` are not compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`inspect.getargspec()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#classes-and-functions):

> #### `inspect.getargspec(func)`
>
> Get the names
> and default values of a function’s
> arguments. A tuple of four things is
> returned: *(args, varargs, varkw,
> defaults)*. args is a list of the
> argument names (it may contain nested
> lists). varargs and varkw are the
> names of the * and ** arguments or
> None. defaults is a tuple of default
> argument values or None if there are
> no default arguments; if this tuple
> has n elements, they correspond to the
> last n elements listed in args.
>
> *Changed in version 2.6: Returns a
> named tuple ArgSpec(args, varargs,
> keywords, defaults).*

Comment: oh very nice... exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What would you be basing the compatibility on? The number of arguments? Python has variable length argument lists, so you never know if two functions might be compatible in that sense. Data types? Python uses duck typing, so until you use an isinstance test or similar inside the function, there is no constraint on data types that a compatibility test could be based on.

So in short: No.

You should rather write good docstrings, such that any user of your API knows what the function he is giving you has to do, and then you should trust that the function you get behaves correctly. Any "compatibility" check would either rule out possibly valid functions or give you a false sense of "everything is exactly as it should be."

The pythonic way of exposing an API is: Write good documentation, such that people know what they need to know, and trust that they do the right thing. In critical positions you can still use `try: except:`, but anybody who is misusing your API because they just didn't care to read the doc shouldn't be given a false sense of security. And someone who did read your doc and wants to use it in a totally acceptable way should not be denied the possibility to use it on the grounds of the way they declared a function.

Comment: Yes, number of arguments. I know I can't check for much more, but I think it's nice to the user of the module to reject a given method/function as early as possible (it's a simple event handling mechanism)

Comment: But this way you will reject a possibly perfectly valid function just because it's declared as def func(*args) or def func(a,b,foo="default"). Just keep that in mind.

Comment: @balpha: this can be checked too using inspect.getargspec. It reports if there are *args and **kwargs arguments.

Comment: Yes, but you would end up with no information at all. I have edited my answer to hopefully make my statement a little bit clear.

Comment: +1, you have a very valid point that should at least be thought about before implementing such a feature.

Comment: I think this answer needs to take type annotations in consideration.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb Possibly, but this answer is from 2009  Maybe post a new answer that takes modern Python into account.

Comment: @balpha sorry but I did not notice that, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Although Python is *Dynamically Typed* language, but there is a strong notion of types in python (*Strongly typed*). And after the introduction of type hints it is possible now to check for functions interchangeability. But first let us state the following:

**The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):**

If type `t2` is a subtype of type `t1` then an object of type `t1` should be replaceable by object of type `t2`.

**The Contra/Covariance of `Callable` type:**

- `Callable[[], int]` is a subtype of `Callable[[], float]` (Covariance).

  This one is intuitive: a callable that eventually evaluate to `int` could replace a function that evaluate to `float` (ignore the args list for a moment).
- `Callable[[float], None]` is a subtype of `Callable[[int], None]` (Contravariance).

  this one is a little bit confusing, but remember, a callable that operate on integers may perform an operation that are not defined on floats such as, `>>` `<<`, while a callable that operate on float will certainly not perform any operation that is not defined on integers (because integer is subtype of float). So a callable that operates on a float may replace a callable that operates on an integer but not via versa (ignoring return types).

From the above we conclude that: For a callable `c1` to be replaceable by callable `c2`, the following should satisfy:

1. `c2` return type should be a subtype of `c1` return type.
2. For argument list of `c1`:  `(a1, a2,...an)` and the argument list of `c2`: `(b1, b2,...bn)`, `a1` should be `a1` subtype `b1`, `a2` subtype of `b2` and so on.

**Implementation**

Simple implementation would be (ignoring `kwargs` and variable length argument lists):

```
from inspect import getfullargspec

def issubtype(func1, func2):
  """Check whether func1 is a subtype of func2, i.e func1 could replce func2"""
  spec1, spec2 = getfullargspec(func1), getfullargspec(func2)
  
  if not issubclass(spec1.annotations['return'], spec2.annotations['return']):
    return False
  
  return all((issubclass(spec2.annotations[arg2], spec1.annotations[arg1]) for (arg1, arg2) in zip(spec1.args, spec2.args)))
```

Examples:

```
from numbers import Integral, Real


def c1(x :Integral) -> Real: 
  pass

def c2(x: Real) -> Integral:
  pass

print(issubtype(c2, c1))
print(issubtype(c1, c2))

class Employee:
  pass

class Manager(Employee):
  pass

def emp_salary(emp :Employee) -> Integral:
  pass

def man_salary(man :Manager) -> Integral:
  pass

print(issubtype(emp_salary, man_salary))
print(issubtype(man_salary, emp_salary))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
False
```